# Run repeatable numerical tests in the cloud

Tags: optimization, experimental-optimization

In numerical tests of optimization algorithms, one often reads "We used a XY computer with X GB RAM for the experiments".

Usually, when I want to compare my results with theirs, I do not have an XY computer, but a YZ computer. And rerunning the tests of others is often difficult because I do not have the code.

I wonder whether one of the large cloud providers allows you to configure a virtual server in a way that others could easily do the same.

Answer (score 8):

If the purpose of the comparison is to compare solution times (as opposed to validating the answers obtained), my feeling is that the XY v. YZ computer should not be an issue. Getting the source code (or binary) for the other algorithm is definitely a problem. Assuming you have their code (and that it runs on your computer, which may require getting the source and recompiling), and assuming you have enough memory for both methods, I think you can do a plausible comparison. If one algorithm has more stringent hardware requirements than the other (e.g., they need 16GB of RAM to solve problems you can solve in 4GB), that is worth noting. Memory aside, the primary difference between an XY and a YZ computer will be CPU speed and number of simultaneous threads it can handle (which relates to number of cores). Neither should dictate whether an algorithm can or cannot solve a problem (whereas memory might); they just affect solution speed. So running both methods on your computer v. theirs is like running a race on one track v. a different track: as long as both competitors are on the same track, it's a fair race.

For me, a trickier issue in algorithm races lies in comparability of the coding. If my code is in Python and theirs is compiled C code, they may have an inherent speed advantage unrelated to the wonderfulness of their algorithm. Even with the same language, differences in compilers could account for some speed differences. Similarly, if one method is coded by someone who is adept at optimizing for speed and the other is coded by someone who knows the math well but is a dabbler in coding, the "tighter" code might win even if the other algorithm is inherently better.

To get at the cloud part, I'm not aware of a cloud platform that lets you choose between different CPUs. (I think some of them let you configure the amount of RAM and possibly the number of cores, but not Intel XXX chip v. AMD yyy chip, say.) On the other hand, I'm no expert on cloud platforms.

Comment: I am not sure about the comment on competitors on the same track. All it takes is to hit the wrong size of a CPU's L1 cache to cause incredible slow-downs (or speed-ups) for one particular code but not for another.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ has some info on the used cpus - sometimes it seems that they use just one specific cpu for certain instance types.

Answer (score 5):

> I wonder whether one of the large cloud providers allows you to configure a virtual server in a way that others could easily do the same.

- The [NEOS Server](https://neos-server.org/neos/) is a **free** internet-based service for solving numerical optimization problems. Hosted by the Wisconsin Institute for Discovery at the University of Wisconsin in Madison, the NEOS Server provides access to more than [60 state-of-the-art solvers](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html) in more than a dozen optimization categories. There are [3rd party submission tools](https://neos-guide.org/content/third-party-tools) that allow you to write a simple program at home and submit your job to the server. See the [NEOS FAQ](https://neos-guide.org/content/FAQ) for details.
- [OpenDreamKit](https://opendreamkit.org/try/) offers a [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) [notebook](https://mybinder.org/) to: [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Overview/Capabilities/links.html) (which supports [OpenMath](https://www.openmath.org/)), [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) (number theory) or try the [simple web interface](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html), [SageMath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SageMath#Software_packages_contained_in_SageMath) (includes **R**, and a lot more), and [Singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_(software)) (a computer algebra system for polynomial computations with special emphasis on the needs of commutative and non-commutative algebra, algebraic geometry, and singularity theory).
- [Singular Online](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de:8003/).
- [Online Solver](http://online-optimizer.appspot.com/?model=builtin:default.mod) for the [GNU Linear Programming Kit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Linear_Programming_Kit) from the book: "[Linear and Integer Optimization - Theory and Practice](http://www.lio.yoriz.co.uk/)", by Gerard Sierksma and Yori Zwols.
- [WolframAlpha Optimizer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/applied-mathematics/optimization/).
- You can install [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/) on [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/) (free year long trial) and Stack Overflow offers some support: "[How to install ortools library on Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55191430/3648282)".
- [PHPSimplex](http://www.phpsimplex.com/en/) is an online tool for solving linear programming problems.
- [OPTIL.io](https://www.optil.io/optilion/) is the on-line judge system that receives algorithmic solutions of optimization problems in a form of source code from the crowd of developers, compiles it, executes in a homogeneous run-time environment and objectively evaluates using the set of test cases. Problems that are solved can be provided by external companies or scientists. Solutions can be submitted in almost any programming language.

Comment: I think what Fabian is aiming at is the possibility to have similar hardware which - to the best of my knowledge - you have no influence over for the computing platforms you mention. I'm not even sure that they all tell you their specific hardware setup.

Comment: @JakobS - One interpretation is that his computer isn't capable and that better capabilities are desired, another is that he desires to use the same computer. In either case I've offered an answer. The first paragraph of my answer addresses your last point and to your penultimate one that is addressed by two of my suggestions.

Comment: jep, you are right. I missed that last point in your answer. The service looks interesting and it seems that they have a specified setup of hardware they are using for benchmarking.